# Is it possible to set TypeScript interface key using method

Tags: typescript

I have an interface let's say:

```
interface SampleInterface {
    [key: string]: string;
}
```

Usually we would define a constant as:

```
const sampleConstant: SampleInterface = {
    key: 'value'
}
```

Why can't I do

```
const sampleConstantWithMethod: SampleInterface = {
    someMethod(): 'value'
}


function someMethod(): string {
    return 'key'
}
```

Is there some work around to this, while still using an Interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names), which is indicated by wrapping the key expression in square brackets like so:

```
const sampleConstantWithMethod: SampleInterface = {
    [someMethod()]: 'value' // okay
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpwLYAcA2ECS408SyA3gLABQytyA2gNYQCeAXMgM5hSgDmAXQ7deIPgG5qAX2qyqCAPYhuXTLggBhJdzjgO6bHkKRYiFAF5y1OsmbtkAcgBucHAFcID6XOow3IBDBgJS4FDAgAWQgwAAsFABMACgBKYR5+Kxo6KGi3KBBHOy8qGSo5RWUwVUNNbTBdMAB1YFio2IT9NSMiU1JLSizaek4wyOi4pOShRxd3T28yqiA)

Comment: That's awesome, thanks a ton for the quick reply.